# Запятая. Однородные члены?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, однородные-неоднородные-определения

> *Мы шли вдоль набережной, я чувствовал морской(,) солёный запах.*

В данном контексте **морской** и **солёный** — однородные члены? Запятая нужна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Мы шли вдоль набережной, (и) я чувствовал **морской, солёный запах.***

**Пояснение**

В этом предложении запятая нужна, определения **однородные, сближенные по значению** (соленый, так как морской). Чувствовать мы можем **соленый запах**, а таким бывает запах моря.

**Примеры:**

(1)  Работает, свистит в снастях настоящий **морской, соленый** ветер. [Андрей Некрасов. Приключения капитана Врунгеля (1937-1939)]

(2) Увлекала и возбуждала жажду, как **морская соленая** влага: раз попил ― потом уже трудно залить жар… [Ф. Д. Крюков. Новым строем // «Русские Ведомости», 1917]

Comment: Но ведь во втором примере неоднородные определения. Тоже ведь соленая, так как морская.

Comment: Там описаны заранее известные свойства морской воды. .А в заданном предложения речь идет о конкретных ощущениях в реальной ситуации.  Мы чувствуем запах соли и понимаем, что это запах моря.

Comment: Но ведь если мы идем рядом с морем (вдоль набережной), мы разве не знаем, что морская вода является соленой? (Пресных морей не бывает.)

Comment: Т.е. она возбуждала, как морская солёная влага. Но этой морской солёной влаги нет в реальности, поэтому ощутить её невозможно, а можно только вспомнить (взять из головы), что морская вода (влага) на вкус солёная.

Comment: Запах моря реально существует, мы без труда отличаем его от других запахов. В нашем сознании он воспринимается прежде всего как запах морской соли,  но также  водорослей, морских животных и т.д. В заданном предложении ключевым словом для определения однородности является глагол "чувствовать".

Comment: Я имела в виду, что этой морской солёной влаги нет в реальности КОНКРЕТНОЙ (того момента), поэтому и прочувствовать её нельзя, а можно только вспомнить о ней.